# Printing a string in alphabetical order in c

Tags: c, string, alphabetical

I edited my code by adding another loop like in bubble sort. but it is working only for 1st word and not for other words. please tell me my mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int i,j,temp,ary[2000];
    char str[2000];
    printf("Enter string \n");
    fgets(str,sizeof str, stdin);
    for(j=0;str[j]!='\n';j++)
    {
        ary[j]=("%d",str[j]);
        printf("\n%d\n",ary[j]);
        printf("%c\n",ary[j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for(j=0;str[j]!='\n';j++)
    {
        for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            if(ary[j]<ary[i])
            {
                temp=ary[j];
                ary[j]=ary[i];
                ary[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nString in alphabetical order\n");
    for(j=0;str[j]!='\n';j++)
        printf("%c\t",ary[j]);
}
```

Comment: Please tidy up the indetation

Comment: And what are these statement `ary[j]=("%d",str[j]);`?

Comment: @EdHeal can you please explain me what is indentation?

Comment: @EdHeal it will store equivalent integer(ASCII value) to array ary[]

Comment: You shouldn't use `puts`.  Just use `printf("%s\n", str);`.

Comment: `arr[j] = (int) str[j]`?

Comment: @Bob `ary[j]=("%d",str[j]);` equals `ary[j] = str[j];`

Comment: @bob - You started off with main on the right track with indentation. Lost the plot with `for`. I will fixx it

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect. It will only put the _largest_ letter to the last place. You need to repeat this process `strlen(str)` times.

Comment: - I think @bob wants to implement a bubble sort - another loop is required

Comment: Hey thanx @EdHeal this was the only problem... Another loop was required! :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sry by mistake I wrote that... Nw its working.. Thanx :)